# Nearest time-of-day value in List

Tags: java, date, arraylist, time

Is there any way to display element of a list (or any other that might do similar function) comparing to current time.
So, I made an arraylist that contains time, which doesn't have any pattern of repetition, using method to increase it for 10 min (for instance) won't to.

I have following:

Date function that has current time:

```
Date date = new Date(); 
DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
```

ArrayList that has time that I need:

```
ArrayList<String> time = new ArrayList<String>();

        time.add("5:40");
        time.add("6:40");
        time.add("8:30");
        time.add("9:45");
        time.add("10:35");
        time.add("11:10");
        time.add("11:55");
        time.add("12:20");
        time.add("13:30");
        time.add("14:55");
        time.add("16:00");
        time.add("16:30");
        time.add("17:30");
        time.add("19:00");
        time.add("20:10");
        time.add("21:10");
```

Now I'm curious, and also because I'm new to this, is there a way to do next:

**1)** Considering there will be a lot of arrays that will have time, is there a way (perhaps with some code examples) to write a method that will have an argument so user can choose which 'time' they want it to be displayed?

**2)** Will there be need to use loop once (in this case 'time' array) it reaches the end, or can it be written so it automatically goes to beginning based on current time.

**3)** Code optimisation: can this be written in more practical way?

I am fairly new to this, so any help (with guidance and code examples) is much appreciated so I can use it in this project and as learning material for future ones.

Comment: I suggest you try something and we can help you improve it when you have a problem. I also suggest you try the new JSR-310 API instead of using `Date` and `DateFormat` i.e. use `LocalTime` instead.

Comment: Can I suggest that you don't radically change your question on the basis of answers. It doesn't make sense that it starts "After I altered the code, using one that was provided by mr.Bourque..." - this feels like reading a novel with the first few pages torn out. Instead, stick in a horizontal rule (`----` on its own line) at the bottom of the question, and post the updated code.

Comment: @D'Jok you should not change your question like this - it makes the existing answers irrelevant which is not nice to those who took the time to write them. If you have an additional question you should ask it separately.

Comment: @assylias I understand and apologies for inconvenience and I changed to the old question. I do have few questions for your code sample, if you have time to answer them?

Comment: @D'Jok Yes you can certainly ask questions.

Comment: @assylias Referring to my question above, specifically to point 1 and 2, how to write a loop that will just return that one element, and once it reaches its end it will go to the beginning? So far whenever I write it, it just prints out that time (which is good) but multiple times.
And, as mentioned above, can this be placed in a method because there will be a lot of 'time' arrays? (and how).
Thank you.

Comment: @D'Jok If you use the code in my answer there is no need to loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @BasilBourque, I suggest storing the times as LocalTimes - but I would also suggest using a [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) such as [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) instead of a `List` (I'm assuming that the times in your list are all unique).

The idea is that `TreeSet` has [a `ceiling` method that does exactly what you need](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#ceiling-E-):

> Returns the least element in this set greater than or equal to the given element, or null if there is no such element.

You can then write:

```
TreeSet<LocalTime> times = new TreeSet<> ();
times.add(LocalTime.parse("05:40"));
times.add(LocalTime.parse("06:40"));
times.add(LocalTime.parse("08:30"));
//...

LocalTime ceiling = times.ceiling(LocalTime.now());
if (ceiling != null) //do something with it
```

Comment: Quick question: if I leave first 3 values of treeset and try to print out ceiling, it won't show anything because it looks at time with 24hrs value, so once it reaches midnight it will start again?
I ask this because I never used treeset

Comment: If the "highest" time in the set is 23:30 and you call ceiling(23:50) then you will get null. It's up to you to decide what to do in that case - you may want to return the first value (05:40), which you can access with `times.first()`

Comment: @D'Jok FYI, you can build a `List` as I showed in my answer (to retain original data including duplicates) *and* build a `TreeSet` as shown here (to call `ceiling`) by simply passing the `List` to constructor of `TreeSet`. `TreeSet<LocalDate> treeSet = new TreeSet<>( list );`

Comment: @assylias Worked like a charm. I do have a question: if I have larger number of those lists (like above) and use 'switch' which will have 'if' statements to control what list will be shown, how much of an performance impact will it cause? Would it be easier to create method which will have that functionality or leave it as such?

Comment: @D'Jok It is difficult to say without more information. I suggest you ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

## java.time

Use the [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class rather than `String` to represent your values. A `LocalTime` object is for time-of-day without a date and without a time zone.

Create your [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

```
List<LocalTime> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

### Parsing

Populate the `List` by parsing the input strings. If your input strings comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard including a padded zero on single-digit hour, then you need not define any formatting pattern as `LocalTime` can directly parse such values.

```
list.add( LocalTime.parse( "09:45" ) );
list.add( LocalTime.parse( "10:35" ) );
list.add( LocalTime.parse( "11:10" ) );
```

If your input strings lack the padding zero, then define and use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "h:m" );
…
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse( input , formatter );
```

### Sorting

Sort the `List`. The [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) static method is one way.

```
Collections.sort( list );
```

### Current time

Get the current time. For this a time zone is required ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)), as the wall-clock time for any moment various around the world by time zone. Use a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), never the 3-4 letter abbreviations commonly seen such as `EST` or `IST`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now( zoneId );
```

### Loop the list

Loop the `List` comparing each element in the list to `now` using whatever rules you have in mind for defining “nearest”. The [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class tracks a span of time as a total number of seconds plus a fractional second in nanoseconds.

Note that `Duration` class has various methods to assist with comparing. The [`abs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#abs--) method gives an [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) (converting negatives to positives). The [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#compareTo-java.time.Duration-) method tells you if one duration is larger, smaller, or equal to another.

```
…
for ( LocalTime localTime : list ) {
    Duration duration = Duration.between( now , localTime );
    …
}
```

## `NavigableSet`

If you don't mind losing any possible duplicate time values, use a [NavigableSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) and its [`ceiling`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#ceiling-E-) method as shown in [the correct answer by Assyrians](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36542353/642706).

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be best to use actual Date objects and just compare them. However, if you need to do it using strings, you could write a compare function that takes two dates and outputs the difference between them in minutes.

```
int compare(String d1, String d2) {
 //split the strings based on the ":"
 string d1Split[] = d1.split(":");
 string d2Split[] = d2.split(":");

 //convert each one to minutes - note this assumes the string will always be formatted like "hours:minutes:anything else is irrelevant"
 d1Mins = d1Split[0] * 60 + d1Split[1];
 d2Mins = d2Split[0] * 60 + d2Split[1];

 //return the absolute value of the difference between the times in minutes - note this assumes the times will be part of the same day
 return Math.abs(d1Mins - d2Mins);
}
```

Once you have a compare function, all you need to do is go through the array and compare each element to the current date, storing the closest one.

```
int leastDifference = 999999;
String now = dateformat.format(date);
String closest = "";
for (String toCompare : time) {
 int comparison = compare(toCompare, now);
 if (comparison < leastDifference) {
  leastDifference = comparison;
  closest = toCompare;
 }
}
```

And closest will contain the string you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

1. get the HH:MM part of current time;
2. sort your `time` list
3. use binary search:

`String search(String currHrs, List time, int start, int end) {
    if (start == end && time.get(start) > currHrs)
        return time.get(start);
    else
        return currHrs;
    int mid = (start + end) >> 1;
    // discard one half at a time.
    return (time.get(mid) > currHrs) ? search(currHrs, time, start, mid): search(currHrs, time, mid + 1, end);
}`